# How to do join in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I am still trying to grasp how mongodb query works. Maybe this is duplicate, but I cant find the exact scenario.

I my head I have this query

```
SELECT
 a.f1,
 a.f2,
 b.f1,
 b.f3 -- or select the all column of b (b.*)
FROM tableA as a
inner join tableB as b
 on(a.f1 = b.f1)
WHERE some conditions here
```

And the closest solution I can think is to use `$lookup`, but cant make it right.

And tried like this.

```
collectionA.aggregate({
 $lookup: {
  from: 'collectionB',
  localField: 'f1',
  foreignField: 'f1',
  as: 'b'
 }
})
// But I don't know what next here.
// I tried to combine the syntax of find query but with no avail.
```

Please help thanks.

**Edit:**

Actually I query the tableA like this

```
tableA.find({
 $and: [{
  schedule: {
   $gte: new Date(from),
   $lte: new Date(to)
  }
 }, {
  f1: {
   $in: some values here
  }
 }]
})
```

And I want to add the data from the table.

Comment: next, you might need to add `$match` to filter same like where clause in SQL after joining. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: hmm I will look at it.

Comment: Just saw your update. Place the match before lookup for collection a. {$match:your criteria from find goes here }. For query criteria on collection b you will need to $unwind b followed  by $match after lookup stage.

Comment: I add edit for the query on the tableA.

Comment: @Veeram thanks, I will try. Still reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now.

```
collectionA.aggregate([{
 $match: {
  $and: [{
   schedule: {
    $gte: new Date(from),
    $lte: new Date(to)
   }
  }, {
   f1: {
    $in: some values
   }
  }]
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'collectionB',
  localField: 'f1',
  foreignField: 'f1',
  as: 'b'
 }
}, {
 $project: {...}
}])
```

Thanks.